# How to call SparkMLLib algorithms using R or SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying use to SparkR and R as front end to develop machine learning models. 
I want to make use Spark's MLLib which works on distributed data frames. Is there anyway to call spark MLLib algorithm from R?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no.  We will have to wait  Apache Spark 1.5 for sparkR-mllib bindings.

Comment: Yes, please check this.  Lot of things changed from the time of original answer.  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html