# Is there a way to connect sparkR with MLlib library?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am using spark ver 1.4. There is extra API for R users - sparkR.

I managed to launch sparkR and to convert R's `data.frame` to spark's `DataFrame` with the following command

```
irisDF <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)
```

I am wondering if there's a way to somehow connect now with spark MLlib library to proceed Logistic Regression - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html or maybe is there away to reconvert `DataFrame` to regular `data.frame` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call SparkMLLib algorithms using R or SparkR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309983/how-to-call-sparkmllib-algorithms-using-r-or-sparkr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way yet to connect with Spark MLlib, this should be released in the next version.  You can however reconvert a DataFrame to a data.frame by

```
collect(irisDF)
```